# Running Python IDLE only works with remote into desktop?

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-10.2, installation, python.exe-stopped-working

An extremely odd issue.  I have python scripts I use, pretty straight forward.  I use them to automate printing of maps in Arcmap (10.2).  I work from home and in my office.  When I work from home I remote into my desktop at my office. I open IDLE to run one of my scripts, If I remote into my computer it works fine.  When I am in the office and using my desktop directly, IDLE crashes saying "Python.exe has stopped working" and that's it.

Any ideas what could be causing this or potential fixes?

I am running python 2.7

Comment: That is really odd, and quite difficult to diagnose. Can you run the scripts locally in a CMD window? Or through the python console of ArcMap/ArcCatalog? Does your workplace use a login script?

Comment: Whenever IDLE randomly crashes without warning on me I'll copy/paste the script into the ArcGIS Python window. I can oftentimes see what error is returned.